# How can create two local strategy in same porject for different user'?

Tags: node.js, api, sequelize.js, passport-local

I am working on project where i have to create two login or different user employee or customer how can create two local passport in node js with sequelize

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't find it in the docs but `passport.use()` can receive `name` as the first param.

```
passport.use('local-employee', new LocalStrategy(...))

passport.use('local-customer', new LocalStrategy(...))
```

full example:

```
const express = require('express')
const passport = require('passport');
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local');

const app = express();
app.use(require('cookie-parser')());
app.use(require('body-parser').urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(require('express-session')({
    secret: 'BAH',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
  }));

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user);
});

passport.use('local-employee', new LocalStrategy(
    function (username, password, done) {
        console.log(username, password);
        // get user from employee source
        user = {username, password, type: 'employee'};
        return done(null, user);
    }
));

passport.use('local-customer', new LocalStrategy(
    function (username, password, done) {
        console.log(username, password);
        // get user from customer source
        user = {username, password, type: 'customer'};
        return done(null, user);
    }
));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());


app.post('/employee/login',
    passport.authenticate('local-employee'),
    function (req, res) {
        res.json(req.user)
    });

app.post('/customer/login',
    passport.authenticate('local-customer'),
    function (req, res) {
        res.json(req.user)
    });

app.listen(3000)
```

```
{
  "name": "passport-local",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-session": "^1.17.2",
    "passport": "^0.4.1",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Getting  error "unknown authenticate strategy " Local- customer"

Comment: can you post a code snippet? and I added `package.json` for good measure

Comment: I add the code & mention the filename on the top of code

Comment: passport.use should be call with *Name* then *Strategy*.  `passport.use( "local-recuriter",  new localpassport(...))`)